# Python: relative import imports whole package

Tags: python

I just noticed that relative import like this:

```
from .foo import myfunc
print myfunc  # ok
print foo  # ok
```

imports both foo and myfunc. Is such behaviour documented anywhere? Can I disable it?

-- Update

Basically problem is following.

`bar/foo/__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['myfunc']

def myfunc(): pass
```

`bar/__init__.py`:

```
from .foo import *
# here I expect that there is only myfunc defined
```

`main.py`:

```
import foo
from bar import *  # this import shadows original foo
```

I can add `__all__` to the `bar/__init__.py` as well, but that way I have to repeat names in several places.

Comment: Please provide information about your package layout and the file these statements occur in.  (My guess is that these lines are in `__init__.py`.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes, __init__.py . I will update question.

Comment: it is another reason to avoid wildcard imports.

Comment: Your actual problem seems to be that `from bar import *` shadows a name.  This is one of [many reasons why you shouldn't use `from bar import *` in scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/in-python-why-is-import-bad).

Comment: btw, absolute import behaves the same: `from bar.foo import myfunc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your package layout is

```
my_package/
    __init__.py
        from .foo import myfunc
    foo.py
        def myfunc(): pass
```

The statement `from .foo import myfunc` first imports the module `foo`, generally without introducing any names into the local scope.  After this first step, `myfunc` is imported into the local namespace.

In this particular case, however, the first step also imports the module into the local namespace: sub-modules of packages are put in the package's namespace upon importing, regardless from where they are imported.  Since `__init__.py` is also executed in the package's namespace, this happens to conincide with the local namespace.

You cannot reasonably disable this behaviour.  If you don't want the name `foo` in your package's namespace, my advice is to rename the module to `_foo` to mark it as internal.

Comment: Thanks. By some reason I thought that this behaviour is unique to relative imports, but actually absolute imports behave the same way. I am lucky that I did not hit this behaviour before :)

Comment: @VladimirMihailenco: Note that "this behaviour" is also the only sensible thing to do for Python.  The `import` statement imports `my_package.foo`, so after the import, `my_package.foo` should better be available.

Comment: yes, I have no excuses :) Looks like I misused `__all__` and wildcard imports all the time.