# Why delete modules in __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-import

I am doing some research in the PyTorch source code. In [this file](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/__init__.py) the authors actually delete the modules.

```
from .adadelta import Adadelta  # noqa: F401
from .adagrad import Adagrad  # noqa: F401
from .adam import Adam  # noqa: F401

del adadelta
del adagrad
del adam
```

What is the rationale for this?

Comment: Interesting question. Some preliminary Googling yields https://stackoverflow.com/a/126499/1008938 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496246/1008938, but I think this deserves its own question.

Comment: Because they don't want to meet expose those names in that namespace, presumably

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a way to factor out functionality into submodules without making the submodules part of the public API. A quirk of the import system is that [this sort of relative import ends up putting the submodules in the parent's namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11581703/364696), so a user could do something like:

```
import torch.optim
```

then follow up by accessing attributes of `torch.optim.adadelta` without ever having explicitly imported `torch.optim.adadelta`. While some Python built-in packages work this way, and it won't be undone because too many people depend on it by accident (e.g. people who only `import os`, then use `os.path` APIs), in general it's best to avoid this sort of data leakage. Importing `torch.optim` should only provide access to the specific names listed, without providing any guarantees about which submodules will be imported automatically.

By doing this, people can't accidentally take a dependency on being able to use `torch.optim.adadelta` after importing only `torch.optim`, so the developers are free to refactor it to move implementations of specific classes and other APIs around, without making special efforts to ensure `import torch.optim` also imports all those submodules just to preserve behaviors from code that performed improper/incomplete imports.